# PhoneGap Build facebookconnect plugin problems

Tags: android, html, phonegap-build

i'm new with PhoneGap build and i'm tryng to write a simple app with a button for facebook login. In PhoneGap build documentation i found is very simple to add this plugin

```
index.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha256.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/facebookConnectPlugin.js"></script>
<script src="js/jq.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="contenuto">
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" class='bt_loginProprietario'>Login</a>
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" class='bt_loginFacebook'>Login con facebook</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>

jq.js
function loginFacebook(){
facebookConnectPlugin.login( ["email"], 
                    function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
                    function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) };
};
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#contenuto').on('click','.bt_loginFacebook',function(){
loginFacebook();
});
});
```

in PG build i see the plugin correctly loaded but when i try to execute the app on my android phone nothing happens when i click on button. i tried to execute in my browser and i receive the error "cordova is not defined

thx for the help this is my first post, i don't understand what is wrong

update
with your suggestion my jq.js now has this code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
$('#contenuto').on('click','.bt_loginFacebook',function(){
loginFacebook();
});
});
```

but when i press the button nothing happens, i saw an error in my chrome console that says cordova is not defined

help pls

Answer (score 0):

This is very common for person new to cordova/phonegap.

You are using a facebook plugin for phonegap. Phonegap REQUIRES that you wait until the **deviceready** event fires before you access any phonegap or 3rd-party plugin services. This blog post explains in more detail.

*FYI – Cordova events must be run after deviceReady*
http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/07/15/fyi-cordova-events-must-be-run-after-deviceready

Comment: Thx a lot i'll try asap. Thanks